# SwiftUI + Dynamic action closure for Button

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I am exploring SwiftUI and I was able to create a subclass of `Button`.

The subclass contains `image` & `title` properties, which makes it a reusable component.

But I am not able to define dynamic action behavior for `Button` class.

Please refer code below.

**Subclass of Round Button:**

```
struct RoundButton: View {
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("Button pressed")
            }){
                Image(image)                
                   .renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.template))
            }
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .accentColor(.white)

            Text(title)
                .font(.footnote)
        }
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
HStack(alignment: .center) {
    Spacer(minLength: 50)
    RoundButton(image: "chat", title: "message")
    Spacer()
    RoundButton(image: "call", title: "call")
    Spacer()
    RoundButton(image: "video", title: "video")
    Spacer()
    RoundButton(image: "mail", title: "mail")
    Spacer(minLength: 50)
}
```

You will see that `action` block print a message here.

I would like to know how we can pass a function for a button's action event?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Button update ...

```
struct RoundButton: View {
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: action){
                Image(image)
                   .renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.template))
            }
    ...
```

Usage update ...

```
RoundButton(image: "chat", title: "message") {
    print("Button pressed")
}
```

Comment: Hi, i would like to know how we can go to a specific view upon clicking that button, means I need to pass a view instead of just printing some text. Can you please me out with the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way that you could just create your custom button without given an action to it! and if you need to give an action you could do it as well, like example in ContentView:

***PS: I noticed that you just given the tap or clickable posibility just to Image which makes the tap or click harder! instead you can put all in a VStack and it makes more easier to tap or click for user and also much better animation of being tapped. And also you do not need use cornerRadius for making a Circle, you could use clipShape.***

```
struct RoundButton: View {
    
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var action: (() -> Void)?
    
    init(image: String, title: String, action: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
        self.action = action
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                action?()
            }){
                VStack {
                    Image(image)
                        .renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.template))
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .clipShape(Circle())

                    Text(title)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.black) 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Use case:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        RoundButton(image: "person", title: "person")

        RoundButton(image: "person", title: "person", action: { print("Button pressed") })

        RoundButton(image: "person", title: "person") {
            print("Button pressed") 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point in `Button` without an action? User would expect two elements which looks the same to act the same, e.g. to be a button. I'm using something similar but also disabling the button when there's no action, but it still has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov: Basically we can use a Button with no action when we want it! For example you can start a work with action and in some condition you can give a nil value in case if user tapped! Another reason would be for UI matter, for example you are designing your view and you just want place your objects and things in view, and then start given real code action! Hope that helps you.

Comment: very nice idea to pt the stack *inside* the button, @swiftPunk cheers