# Replacing SwiftUI Button with a custom Button

Tags: swiftui

I would like to extend the SwiftUI.Button so that i can add a type prop and have that type change to different types of my theme buttons. But I am new to Swift and I can't figure out how to have my label and action props be generic.

In other words if i do this

```
import SwiftUI

struct Button: View {
    var type: String = ""
    var action = {}
    var label = {
        Text("Button")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(content: {
            SwiftUI.Button(action: action, label: label)
        })
    }
    
    
}
```

it limits the closure to only allow for label to return text()

how can this be done

also any suggestions on how i should to alter the "alterations" done to the button based on the type.

NOTE:
someone downvoted this because it is similar to [button style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995278/custom-button-in-swiftui-list) query from another user however it is not.

that solution is for simply adding pre-made styles to the default SwiftUI.button struct and that's not my goal.

I'm attempting to extend SwiftUI.Button with a type property that can be passed and will set the styling based that input.

Although they share the same result they are not accomplishing the same goal. My solution will offer a dynamically styled component which can be used throughout the project. without the need of trailing `.buttonStyle(BlueButtonStyle())`

Comment: How you just extend the Button? all the things are the same as before, if it is going work even!

Comment: Also, it sounds like you are describing the a [button style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995278/custom-button-in-swiftui-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swiftui-dynamic-action-closure-for-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389414/swiftui-dynamic-action-closure-for-button)

Comment: @swiftPunk yes everything is the same cause i'm not sure how to go about extending the functionality hence the question...

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you. the combination of both of these can solve my problem thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Conclusion of what swiftPunk put is the following.

```
struct Button<Content: View>: View {
    let type: button_styles
    let action: () -> Void
    let label: () -> Content
    
    enum button_styles {
        case filled
        case outlined
        case plain
    }
    
    
    init(type: button_styles, action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Content ) {
        self.type = type
        self.action = action
        self.label = label
    }
    
    init(type: button_styles, action: @escaping () -> Void, title: String) where Content == Text {
        self.init(type: type, action: action, label: { Text(title) })
    }
    
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, title: String) where Content == Text {
        self.init(type: .plain, action: action, label: { Text(title) })
    }
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.init(type: .plain, action: action, label: label)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        switch type {
        case .filled:
            SwiftUI.Button(action: self.action, label: self.label).buttonStyle(FilledButtonStyle())
        case .outlined:
            SwiftUI.Button(action: self.action, label: self.label).buttonStyle(OutlinedButtonStyle())
        case .plain:
            SwiftUI.Button(action: self.action, label: self.label).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
    
}

struct FilledButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(maxWidth: 108, maxHeight: 34, alignment: .center)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.white.opacity(0.5) : Color.white)
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color("Red").opacity(0.5) : Color("Red"))
            .cornerRadius(20)
            
    }
}
struct OutlinedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(maxWidth: 108, maxHeight: 34, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(Color("Grey"))
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0))
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10).stroke(Color("Grey"), lineWidth: 2))
    }
}

struct PlainButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(maxWidth: 108, maxHeight: 34, alignment: .center)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.white.opacity(0.5) : Color("Grey"))
    }
}
```

which will allow you to use the Button Struct like:

```
Button(type: .outlined, action: { print("pressed") }, title: "Button")
```

or

```
Button(action: { print("pressed") }, title: "Button")
```

or

```
Button(action: addItem, label: {
    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
})
```

Answer (score 5):

As I see you are trying re create apple Button, You can do like this, and then do your customisation in body:

---

```
struct Button<Content: View>: View {
    
    let action: () -> Void
    let label: () -> Content
    
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.action = action
        self.label = label
    }
    
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, title: String) where Content == Text {
        
        self.init(action: action, label: { Text(title) })
    }

    var body: some View { label().onTapGesture { action() } }
    
}
```

---

***use case:***

```
    Button(action: { print("hello") }, label: { Text("Button") })
```

---

```
    Button(action: { print("hello") }, title: "Button")
```

Comment: My Answer is the most bottom of Button topic! you cannot go deeper than that! :)

Comment: yea i saw your answer from the custom view topic. I would have to mix this solution with Custom Button in SwiftUI List solution.

Comment: Basically with my answer you replace apple Button with your own custom Button! How cool is that! and the best part is here! when you share your code here or there every body could use this custom Button, because I just replicated from real apple Button, so you got your own design plus your code are usable for some who do not have your custom Button!